# Redraw checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, wndproc

I was wondering is it possible to draw a `checkBox` with custom colors for text and tick? I heard it was possible by overriding [`WndProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx) and using [`WM_PAINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I have no experience doing that.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Ok, then why not to use BackColor and ForeColor properties?

Comment: I want the color of the tick blue for example, and the color of the text black.. I cant seem to achieve this with backColor/foreColor.

Comment: This is the right direction: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/27932a94-b63b-4293-ae82-f10171691888/

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, backcolor changes the background color for the entire control. forecolor changes the text color. This is not exactly what the OP is asking. For complete control customization you need to override the OnPaint method and do all the drawing yourself!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an exceptionally basic example of how you can redraw a CheckBox:

```
    public class CustomCheckBox : CheckBox
    {
        public CustomCheckBox()
        {
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pevent);
            if (this.Checked)
            {
                pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16));
            }
            else
            {
                pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16));
            }
        }
    }
```

It works, but its very rough around the edges! However it does illustrate very basically how you can draw custom controls.